# Process in background worker error

Tags: c#, .net, process, backgroundworker

while the execution of a time consuming python script , i would manage the IU with background worker to display a progress bar.

i have used the background worker successfully when i needn't the event `OutputDataReceived` , but the script that i'm using prints some progress values like ("10" , "80",..), so i got to listen the event `OutputDataReceived`.

i get this error : `This operation has already had OperationCompleted called on it and further calls are illegal.` in this line `progress.bw.ReportProgress(v);`.

i tried to use 2 background worker  instances, one executes and the other listens , it gives no errors but it seems do not call the event 'OutputDataReceived' so i don't see any progress in the progress bar.

below the code that i used:

```
    private void execute_script()
    {
             progress.bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler( //progress.bw is reference to the background worker instance
        delegate(object o, DoWorkEventArgs args)
        {

        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "python.exe";
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = @".\scripts\script1.py " + file_path + " " + txtscale.Text;
        //proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        //proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        //proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true; 
        proc.OutputDataReceived += new System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventHandler(proc_OutputDataReceived);
        proc.Start();
        proc.BeginOutputReadLine();

      //proc.WaitForExit();
        //proc.Close();
                   });

           progress.bw.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

 ///the function called in the event OutputDataReceived 
 void proc_OutputDataReceived(object sender, System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        if (e.Data != null)
        {
            int v = Convert.ToInt32(e.Data.ToString()); 
            MessageBox.Show(v.ToString());
         //   report(v);
            progress.bw.ReportProgress(v);

        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("null received"); 


    }
```

Comment: You do know that C#4 supports Python a bit more directly?

Comment: my contraint to Iron python is that , i'm using "Arcpy" so binding Arcpy to Iron python is not fairly easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the `BackgroundWorker`'s `DoWork` handler finishes as soon as the process starts, as there's nothing "waiting" (since you commented out `proc.WaitForExit()`) for the process to finish.  Once the `BackgroundWorker` work handler completes, you can no longer report progress using that instance.

Since `Process.Start` is already asynchronous, there is no reason to use a background worker at all.  You can just marshal the call from `OutputDataReceived` onto the UI thread yourself:

```
///the function called in the event OutputDataReceived 
void proc_OutputDataReceived(object sender, System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    //throw new NotImplementedException();
    if (e.Data != null)
    {
        int v = Convert.ToInt32(e.Data.ToString()); 
        // MessageBox.Show(v.ToString());
        // progress.bw.ReportProgress(v);
        this.BeginInvoke( new Action( () => {
             this.progressBar.Value = v;
        }));
    }
}
```

If you use this, don't create the `BackgroundWorker` at all.

Comment: your solution seems working , but i think that i have an error in script level, because its behaviour changes from standard command line behaviour , so it got just 2 events one with first value "0"and the second with null value , while i'm expecting 10 values of int.

Answer (score 0):

BackGroundWorker has a ReportProgress option that is built just for this.

[BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress Method (Int32, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t.aspx)

Comment: thanks a lot Mr Blam , the ReportProgress  function was the source of the error so i tried to found a workaround to avoid it.